# Align sticky menu under normal menu

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to have two sticky headers.
One is the menu and 1 should be the buy box of a product.
Unfortuantely right now the buy button is ABOVE the menu, and i need it to be below.

I have tried changing the css position but cannot seem to get it to work.
Does anybody have pointers on how I can get this to work?
Much appreciated!

Link:
https://www.agreenstory.de/shop/greenbook/greenbook-a4/

Edit:
This would be the situation I'd like:
http://agreenstory.de/like.jpg

Comment: Firstly, when you scroll up (no matter location on page) the buy appears. Secondly, can't you just _move_ the `<div>` below the element?

Comment: Ideally I would remove that whole ' appear'  thing. I would like it to be sticky below the menu bar. But I think that requires more work.

As this is wordpress it is not always that easy to chagne the <div> positions. Or am I missing something (please tell me if I am wrong haha)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal thing would be to modify the javascript that is enforcing `top: 0px` to use values according to your case scenario.

But as I assume these are third party plugins, you can work-around it by applying  the following styles:

```
#osplugin-header-sticky .header-fixed {
    padding-top: 65px;
}

.fusion-header-wrapper {
    z-index: 200001;
}
```

Please let me know if that gives you the desired result. The black header still sticky-top right on the top edge, while the buy product call to action appears (when you scroll back) below it.

Comment: hah! Thank you.

This fixed part of the problem. It works when I scroll down and it appears; in that case it shows below the menu bar (increase the padding to 95px).

However, as a starting position it is still above the menu.
You can see the changes on the live website.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to remove the fixed top position first:

```html
<header class="oss-header-sticky  " style="top: 0px;">
```

Then you can move the `div` child element of this tag to a desire place , after closed of following tag:

```html
<div class="fusion-header-v1 fusion-logo-left fusion-sticky-menu- fusion-sticky-logo-1 fusion-mobile-logo- fusion-mobile-menu-design-modern ">
```

Comment: Do you mean this line?

<header class="oss-header-sticky <?php echo $options['single_bar_position'] == 'bottom' ? esc_attr( 'bottom' ) : '';  ?> ">

Comment: I was able to remove the bar (like you mentioned) but I am unable to place it in the correct position.
Would this be somewhere in the header file?
Or should I be looking in theme file?